# What are the tools can be use for functional testing for an EXTJS application?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, functional, end-to-end, testing-framework

I have to test an application developed using extjs. Mainly I have to focus on functional testing. Are there any new tools and frameworks that can be used for testing?
I've searched about several tools existing right now like TestNG,Jasmine. But seems to be not working for me as I want them to be.

This system has no service layer. I want to do end to end testing. Since Extjs use dynamic id's for id attribute its hard to capture element by id. As I have found, people have recommended to use css locators and and xpaths to locate elements. But as I know it's not a good practice to use xpaths ans all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You will be more likely to end up using a generic testing framework, via CSS selectors to locate elements.

Answer (score 1):

You've correctly spotted the problematic use of dynamic ids, that makes it hard(er) to write and maintain tests with Selenium.
I'm not entirely sure, but it should be possible for the developers to add (unique) names to each widget, making stuff easier to find.

Regarding your question, '**what are the tools**', I suggest you take a look at Sencha's own testing tool. It's commercial, but there is a 30-day eval version available at **https://www.sencha.com/products/test/#overview**